# Enable/ Disable elements under 'edit' depending on role

Tags: 7, nodes, users

I want some users to have access to certain items under the 'edit' tab but hide others...

I know you can allow a role to 'edit' or not 'edit' a published node content type but that enables and disables the whole of the edit tab!

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question, you need the [Field Permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module. From the project page:

> The Field Permissions module allows site administrators to set field-level permissions to edit, view and create fields on any entity.

This will allow you to grant permission for editing certain fields to a specific user role.